# Qt Designer - this file contains top level spacers

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I use Vertical Spacer separation lable and button

but I get this feedback

[image: but I get this feedback]

So I find the solution, than I set mainwindow layout, but still get same feedback

[image: This is run .py file result]

How can I solve this problem, Thanks.

Comment: Adding a spacer in a splitter doesn't make any sense. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Lable and Button can distance, and when main windows resize they can adjust place , not stay at same place.

Comment: QSplitter is used to optimize space between **widgets**, but, most importantly, provide the user an interface to adjust their sizes. According to your images, there is no requirement for that, so: 1. you either use the splitter as it's intended; 2. you use a *container* widget with a spacer properly put into a layout. I strongly suggest you to read the documentation about QSplitter, layout managers and item spacers, and understand their usage and behavior, as it seems clear that you're using one of them for the wrong reason.

Comment: @Kenisnotme You need to select the splitter, and click *Break Layout*. Then select the centralwidget, and click *Lay Out Vertically*.